# ReactJS Making Component state available outside Component definition

Tags: reactjs

I am building a simple dashboard. I have a object dictionary (`dashboardItems`) holding dashboard items to show (either `<SubComponent1 />` or `<SubComponent 2/>`, a helper function to return the component from the dictionary (`getDashBoardContent()`), and finally I have the dashboard component (`<DashBoard />`). I am passing a prop to `<SubComponent 2/>` by means of a simple state, `optionId`:

```
const dashboardItems = [
  {
    id: 0,
    content: <SubComponent1 />
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    content: <SubComponent2 options={this.state.optionId} />
  }
];

const getDashBoardContent = listItemIndex => {
  return dashboardItems[listItemIndex].content;
};

class DashBoard extends Component {
  state = {
    listItemIndex: 0,
    optionId: 0,
  };

  handleClick = (item, id) => {
    this.setState({
      listItemIndex: item,
      optionId: id,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return
    ...
```

The problem is that React is throwing an error that it cannot read the property `options={this.state.optionId}`. I am assuming that the reason is that the dictionary `dashboardItems` is outside the `Dashboard` component that is defining the state.

What strategies should I use?

*(Note: although I am using Redux in my application, I do not want to use it just to track the item to display in the dashboard)*.

Comment: How your DashBoard and SubComponent relate to each other? Child/parent? Does your SubComponent expect props? Sibling components cannot pass props to each other.

Comment: React 16.3.0 provides a context API that can help you to set up values and get them in any module (provider / consumer) no matter how deeply nested: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html - didn't try myself but looks very helpfull.

Comment: @ElkhanMamedov `<DashBoard />` is the parent of the other subcomponents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the function to set and initialize the components do you mind using the React conditional rendering property such as this:

```
class DashBoard extends Component {
  state = {
    listItemIndex: 0,
    optionId: 0,
  };

  handleClick = (item, id) => {
    this.setState({
      listItemIndex: item,
      optionId: id,
    });
  };

  render() {
  {listItemIndex, optionid} = this.state
    return ()
    {if desired state: <SubComponent1 /> : 
 <SubComponent2 options={this.state.optionId} />
//If desired state render component one else render the other component 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your components in dashboard list into functions like this:

```
const dashboardItems = [
  {
    id: 0,
    content: () => <SubComponent1 />
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    content: (state) => <SubComponent2 options={state.optionId} />
  }
];

class DashBoard extends Component {
   ...

   render() {
     const item = dashboardItems.find(x => x.id === this.state.listItemIndex);

     return (
       <div>
         {item.content(this.state)}
       </div>    
     );
   }
}
```